# Missing proxy for identifier IBFilesOwner

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

We've got an application that on rare occasions crashes with the error:

`Missing proxy for identifier IBFilesOwner`

We understand it to be implying that it can't find File's Owner for one of our nibs (xibs) but we've been through and confirmed they all have valid ones set.

There's practically zero on Google, can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I had the same problem and it turned out that I was doing some threading and I was executing code that should be on the main thread on another thread.
I don't know what you're doing in your app, but hopefully that might give you a clue.

If you share some code we can try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thinking about it we haven't seen it for a while since a colleague made some changes to the Core Data Threading we're doing.

Comment: same problem here, once I moved the appropriate code to the main thread it solved the problem